# how to automate the drag and drop functionality in selenium rc

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I am trying to automate a drag and drop functionality in selenium rc, i am not sure of there is a drag and drop method in the selenium api, any idea please on how such a test can be performed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Selenium RC,

```
selenium.mouseMove("<sourceLocator>");
selenium.mouseDown("<sourceLocator>");
selenium.mouseMove("<destinationLocator>");
selenium.mouseUp("<destinationLocator>");
```

Here is the [link](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/Drag-drop-in-Selenium-RC-961927.S.60933203) to it. It will be better if you start using Selenium Webdriver instead of RC, since it is officially deprecated.

Comment: Hi Vidnesh , thank you for the Info , the thing is that i am still with RC is the with web driver i have got to create a class with every browser unlike RC where you can specify the type of browser you want to test with.

Comment: with every browser? Actually it is easy to work with webdriver since it is directly interacting with the browser native controls. I believe you can get it once you start exploring

Comment: you actually right i should definitely start migrating to webDriver thank you Sir for the above information

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how it works in java, but in js it works in such way

```
driver.actions().dragAndDrop(source, target).perform();
```

This [link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html)
may help to write same code in java =)

Comment: Question was for Selenium-RC. Your solution is for Selenium-Webdriver.